# How can i hear more than one source through only one audio device?

Tags: audio, sound-card, audio-streaming

I was using a Tascam audio interface until last week. At the same time i could get a sound/signal from more than one source (an audio squencer software + ordinary media player) I changed my audio device with an old dj controller (behringer 3000) now i cannot use a software and a media player at the same time. i need to close squencer for using the media player. I guess its about behringer's very basic audio device. I need to understand what is the cause of this situation. What is the difference of these two devices? How do i know is it allowing or not 
when i'm going to buy a new device?

Answer (score 0):

you may use Voicemeeter as virtual mixer to use several application together. Connect Voicemeeter output A1 to your TASCAM audio interface... then connect all applications to Voicemeeter virtual audio input (including virtual ASIO)...